# ViewData Access Array Property in a View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I access in a View the property `Result[] Results { get; set; }` if from the Controller I pass the data with a `ViewData["Information"]`, how can iterate this array property in the view?

```
    {
        [JsonProperty("count")]
        public bool Count { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("next")]
        public Uri Next { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("previous")]
        public object Previous { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public Result[] Results { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public double Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("context")]
        public Context Context { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public long CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing data from controller ViewData["information"]=modalObject.

First collect the response from ViewData["information"] in var field then use that field for iterations using for or foreach loop.

In cshtml page.

```
@{
   var data=ViewData["information"];
  foreach(var item in data.Results){
     //Your razor code.
  }
}
```